# Errors when Pushing Vue.js app with IBM Cloud+Cloud Foundry Node Buildpack

Tags: vue.js, ibm-cloud, npm-install, cloud-foundry, continuous-delivery

I am really new (this is my first time) to using IBM Cloud.I have a Vue.js app that I would like to deploy on IBM Cloud with continuous delivery. I have my Vue project in a GitHub repository, and I would like to be able to deploy the project automatically upon changes to the master branch of the repository. I have successfully set up the tool chain so that the "Delivery Pipeline" runs upon changes to the master branch. See screenshot: 
[image: Tool Chain]

Within the Delivery Pipeline, I have two stages: Build and Deploy. See screenshot 2:
[image: Delivery Pipeline]

I (think) I have successfully set up the Build Stage, where I install npm, then proceed to run the command "npm run build" to create a deployable bundle, with this script:

```
    bash
    #!/bin/bash

    export NODE_VERSION=8
    export NVM_VERSION=0.33.11

    npm config delete prefix \
   && curl -o-
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v${NVM_VERSION} 
    /install.sh | bash \
  && export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" \
  && . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
  && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
  && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
  && nvm use default \
  && node -v \
  && npm -v

echo "Installing NPM"
npm install
echo "NPM install successful"
echo "Attempting npm run build"
npm run build
echo "NPM run build successful"
```

**This is where the uncertainty arises.** I want to deploy the project, which after `npm run build` should just require index.hmtl and build.js, which is in the 'dist' folder.

I don't know if this is necessary, but following the `npm install` and `npm run build` stage, I added this stage, which I really don't know what does. I have only added it because the boilerplate SDK for Node.js™
had this stage prior to the deploy stage, see screenshot 3:
[image: Simple Build Stage]

After this, I have the Deploy stage set to take the 'Simple Build' stage as its input. It deploys it with a simple cloud foundry push command. However, I get these errors in the log, after it downloads the various buildpacks:

```
Staging...
-----> IBM SDK for Node.js Buildpack v3.25.1-20190115-1637
       Based on Cloud Foundry Node.js Buildpack v1.5.24
-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version (latest stable) via 'node-version-resolver'
       Installing Node.js (6.16.0) from cache
       Using default npm version: 3.10.10
-----> Restoring cache
       Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
-----> Building dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json)
-----> Installing App Management
       WARN: App Management cannot be installed because the start script cannot be found.
       To install App Management utilities, specify your 'node' start script in 'package.json' or 'Procfile'.
Checking for Dynatrace credentials
No Dynatrace Service Found (service with substring dynatrace not found in VCAP_SERVICES)
-----> Caching build
       Clearing previous node cache
       Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (nothing to cache)
-----> Build succeeded!
       └── vue@2.6.10

 !     This app may not specify any way to start a node process
       http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/node
Exit status 0
Staging complete
Uploading droplet, build artifacts cache...
Uploading build artifacts cache...
Uploading droplet...
Uploaded build artifacts cache (15.3M)
Uploaded droplet (29.4M)
Uploading complete
Stopping instance 64ed3f5f-71eb-477b-afc1-0e07e2e74fdb
Destroying container
Successfully destroyed container

0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 crashed
FAILED
Error restarting application: Start unsuccessful
```

Any ideas? Where am I going wrong? ***Any help would be greatly appreciated***!

Comment: I have a few questions: - It looks as if your package.json does not have a [start entry](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json). Can you check to see of one is there? - Do you get the same result when you build and do a "cf push" from your desktop? - You talk about the result of your build in a dist directory. Did you cd into it? (looks like you did)

Comment: Thanks for your help! So, I have updated my package.json to have a start entry. I have  "start": "node app.js". What should I have in the app.js file?

Comment: EDIT: I have got it working! I just needed to add the dependencies/require statements in the app.js file, and then I removed that extra 'Simple build" stage.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. I just needed to add the dependencies/require statements in the app.js file (some Express stuff), and then I removed that extra 'Simple build" stage